# Using typescript enum and react to expect string prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to strict type a Button component in React.

**How can I expect a prop with a specific string value?**

My current attempt results in 
`Type '"primary"' is not assignable to type 'ButtonLevel'`

```
enum ButtonLevel {
  Primary = "primary",
  Secondary = "secondary",
  Warning = "warning"
}

interface IButtonProps {
  level: ButtonLevel,
  disabled?: boolean
}

function MyButton(props: IButtonProps) {
  return (<Button>ABC</Button>)
}

function test() {
  return (<MyButton level="primary" ></MyButton>)
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Right... just enter the values pipe separated

```
interface IButtonProps {
  level: "primary" | "secondary" | "warning",
  disabled?: boolean
}

function test() {
  return (<MyButton level="ad" disabled >Continue</MyButton>)
}
```

Which then warns a component consumer the value is invalid.

Answer (score 3):

When you use enum you pass ButtonLevel.Primary not 'primary', the point of enums is to be strongly typed and prevent typos.

Answer (score 3):

you can use `${ButtonLevel}` to get ButtonLevel Enum value.

such as

```
enum ButtonLevel {
  Primary = 'primary',
  Secondary = 'secondary',
  Warning = 'warning',
}

interface IButtonProps {
  level: `${ButtonLevel}`;
// (property) IButtonProps.level: "primary" | "secondary" | "warning"
  disabled?: boolean;
}

function MyButton(props: IButtonProps) {
  return <Button>ABC</Button>;
}

function test() {
  return <MyButton level="primary"></MyButton>;
}
```

Comment: This actually works. I have to admit I was surprised by that. So yes, this is a valid alternative. Although I consider the string literal type solution from the accepted answer as simpler, more straight to the point, less confusing, and therefore preferrable.
But -nonetheless- nice answer.

Comment: Cool! I didn't know you could do this string interpolation of an Enum to string union!

Comment: Depending on how reusable fix you look for, this answer might be better over:
`level: "primary" | "secondary" | "warning"`
because it doesn't force you to harcode the literals.
In my app I have constants like "pirmary", "secondary" etc used all over and with:
**level: `${ButtonLevel}`** everything is centralized in case you should change the literals